# As3 Adding MC from Libary and accesing content inside loaded MC

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, loading, flash-cs6

I have a movieClip I am loading from the Libary and I have properly LINKED it to export with a name of `myMC`. This movieclip contains another movieClip and some properties. Lets call the movieClip inside: `insideMC`.

Here is my code:

```
function loadScreen()
{
    var newMC:MovieClip = new myMC();
    addChild(newMC);
    loadButtons();
}

function loadButtons()
{
    newMC.insideMC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, homeButtons);
}

loadScreen();
```

**HOWEVER, when I call the function `loadButtons()` within the `loadScreen()` function then I get this error.**

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
        at iRosary_fla::MainTimeline/loadButtons()[iRosary_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:83]
        at iRosary_fla::MainTimeline/loadScreen()[iRosary_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:110]
        at iRosary_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()[iRosary_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:103]
```

It is not seeing the `insideMC`. Perhaps because it's calling to fast or not loaded yet. It is calling and loading the `newMC` tho. Just the function `loadButtons()` is not working because it is not seeing the `insideMC` movieClip.  I am sure this is an easy fix but I can't find it anywhere. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`newMC` is a local variable in your `loadScreen()` method, therefore it has no scope in your `loadButtons()` method.

Declare `newMC` as a class member variable and it will have scope in `loadButtons()`

for example :

```
// in class declarations
public var newMC:MovieClip;

function loadScreen()
{
    newMC = new myMC();
    addChild(newMC);
    loadButtons();
}
```

It's important to understand that :

```
var newMC:MovieClip = new myMC();
```

Creates a local variable. From your comments, it sounds like you did have `newMC` as a class variable.  So you assumed that the above line was assigning the new instance to your class member `newMC`, and not the local variable you created.

Comment: I am actually only using the classes Flash creates for me. So I posted this code at the top of my actionscirpt: var newMC:MovieClip; and I am still getting the error. I can go into the lib and click on properties and add something to the myMC class that is being loaded if that  is what you mean.

Comment: You were right. I had this line in the function: var newMC:MovieClip = new myMC(); which was making a new var rather than calling the old one. THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure this is your problem. But to access a movie clip within a movie clip you have to give that "insideMC" an instance name within the first movie clip. Otherwise you'll reference an object that you haven't added to the stage - a null object.

Tutorial on instance names [here](http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/16/1/Instance-Names/Page1.html)

Comment: It has an instance name inside the movie clip and while it was on the stage from the begining it worked fine, but when I tried to load it dynamically it didn't. Do I have to also give it a dynamic instance name as well? It has one hard coded inside already and I am calling it.